# Include both single and multiple text strings with Regex (in Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, regex, ole, open-uri

so I have this problem where I am to list every country in a list in Excel by using Open-URI. Everything is working properly but I can't seem to figure how to get my RegExp-"string" to include single-named countries (like "Sweden") but also countries like South Africa that is separated with a whitespace etc. I hope i've made myself understood fairly and below I will include the relevant pieces of code.

the text I want to match is the following (for example):

```
<a href="wf.html">Wallis and Futuna</a>
<a href="ym.html">Yemen</a>
```

I am currently stuck with this Regexp:

```
/a.+="\w{2}.html">(\w*)<.+{1}/
```

As you see, there is no problem with matching 'Yemen'.
Though I still want the code to be able to match both "Wallis and Futuna AND Yemen.
Perhaps if there was a way to include everything inside the given ">blabla bla<"?
Any thoughts? I would be very grateful!

Comment: It's important to show sample data and the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your test sample,

```rb
/<a[^>]+href="\w{2}.html">([\w\s]+)<\/a>/
```

Comment: A regex based solution is fragile and will fail if the HTML changes. Imagine what will happen if the `href` was missing a trailing `"`, had ` = ` instead of `=`, had punctuation inside the link text, or the tag was missing a closing `</a>`.

Answer (score 5):

It is generally bad to use Regex when dealing with HTML entity extraction

```
require 'nokogiri' 

parser = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(your_html)
country_links = parser.css("a")
country_links.each{|link| puts link['href']; puts link.text;}
```

Comment: I agree. Using regexes for HTML „parsing“ has proven to be a bad idea.

Comment: +1 This is the only really bullet-proof solution. HTML is too irregular for a regex pattern to handle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution with successful result. I might add that the program is only for educational purposes and nevertheless I appriciate your input!